# TexStudio error: The command has been expanded to 11 levels

Tags: errors, texstudio

Whenever I try to compile any TeX document with TexStudio I get this error:

> The command has been expanded to 11 levels. Do you want to continue
>   expanding "txs:///pre-compile |
>   txs:///conditionally-recompile-bibliography"?

[image]

If I press OK I get the same error again and again with a different number and so on.
If I press Cancel I can exit this message.

How can I solve this annoying problem?
I would like to solve it without removing all my configuration (because I have some options for knitr and for two-way navigation).
I guess it has something to do with my configuration.
Reinstalling the program doesn't solve the problem.

[image]
[image]

Here is the content of texstudio.ini, with some non-important lines removed.

```
[General]
IniMode=true

[texmaker]
NotifyShortcutChange=false
Tools\Commands\latex="\"C:/texlive/2016/bin/win32/latex.exe\" -src -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"
Tools\Commands\pdflatex="\"C:/texlive/2016/bin/win32/pdflatex.exe\" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"
Tools\Commands\xelatex="\"C:/texlive/2016/bin/win32/xelatex.exe\" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"
Tools\Commands\lualatex="lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"
Tools\Commands\view-dvi=C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\OpenWith.exe \"?am.dvi\"
Tools\Commands\view-ps=\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat DC\\Acrobat\\AcroDist.exe\" \"?am.ps\"
Tools\Commands\view-pdf-external=\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat DC\\Acrobat\\Acrobat.exe\" \"?am.pdf\"
Tools\Commands\dvips=\"C:/texlive/2016/bin/win32/dvips.exe\" -o %.ps %.dvi
Tools\Commands\dvipng=\"C:/texlive/2016/bin/win32/dvipng.exe\" -T tight -D 120 %.dvi
Tools\Commands\ps2pdf=\"C:/texlive/2016/bin/win32/ps2pdf.exe\" %.ps
Tools\Commands\dvipdf=\"C:/texlive/2016/bin/win32/dvipdfm.exe\" %.dvi
Tools\Commands\bibtex=\"C:/texlive/2016/bin/win32/bibtex.exe\" %
Tools\Commands\bibtex8=\"C:/texlive/2016/bin/win32/bibtex8.exe %
Tools\Commands\biber=\"C:/texlive/2016/bin/win32/biber.exe %
Tools\Commands\makeindex=\"C:/texlive/2016/bin/win32/makeindex.exe %.idx
Tools\Commands\texindy=\"C:/texlive/2016/bin/win32/texindy.exe %.idx
Tools\Commands\makeglossaries=\"C:/texlive/2016/bin/win32/makeglossaries.exe %
Tools\Commands\metapost="\"C:/texlive/2016/bin/win32/mpost.exe -interaction=nonstopmode ?me)"
Tools\Commands\asy=\"C:/texlive/2016/bin/win32/asy.exe ?m*.asy
Tools\Commands\gs=\"C:\\texlive\\2016\\bin\\win32\\rungs.exe\" \"?am.ps\"
Tools\Commands\latexmk="\"C:/texlive/2016/bin/win32/latexmk -pdf -silent -latexoption=\"-synctex=1\" %"
Tools\Commands\quick=txs:///compile | txs:///view
Tools\Commands\compile=txs:///pdflatex
Tools\Commands\view=txs:///view-pdf
Tools\Commands\view-pdf=txs:///view-pdf-internal --embedded
Tools\Commands\bibliography=txs:///bibtex8
Tools\Commands\index=txs:///makeindex
Tools\Commands\glossary=txs:///makeglossaries
Tools\Commands\ps-chain=txs:///latex | txs:///dvips | txs:///view-ps
Tools\Commands\dvi-chain=txs:///latex | txs:///view-dvi
Tools\Commands\pdf-chain=txs:///pdflatex | txs:///view-pdf
Tools\Commands\dvi-pdf-chain=txs:///latex | txs:///dvipdf | txs:///view-pdf
Tools\Commands\dvi-ps-pdf-chain=txs:///latex | txs:///dvips | txs:///ps2pdf | txs:///view-pdf
Tools\Commands\asy-dvi-chain=txs:///latex | txs:///asy | txs:///latex | txs:///view-dvi
Tools\Commands\asy-pdf-chain=txs:///pdflatex | txs:///asy | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///view-pdf
Tools\Commands\pre-compile=" txs:///pre-compile | txs:///conditionally-recompile-bibliography"
Tools\Commands\internal-pre-compile=txs:///pre-compile | txs:///conditionally-recompile-bibliography
Tools\Commands\recompile-bibliography=txs:///compile | txs:///bibliography | txs:///compile
Tools\Commands\svn=
Tools\Commands\svnadmin=
Startup\CheckLatexConfiguration=true
ToolBar\CentralVisible=true
StructureView\ShowLinenumbers=false
StructureView\Indentation=-1
StructureView\IndentIncludes=false
Structure\ShowElementsInComments=false
Structure\MarkStructureElementsBeyondEnd=true
Structure\MarkStructureElementsInAppendix=true
StructureView\ReferenceCommandsInContextMenu=\\ref
Files\New%20File%20Encoding=UTF-8
Files\AutoDetectEncodingFromChars=true
Files\AutoDetectEncodingFromLatex=true
Files\Remember%20File%20Filter=true
Files\Recent%20Files%20Highlighting=@Variant(\0\0\0\x7f\0\0\0\x10StringStringMap\0\0\0\0\0)
Files\RestoreSession=true
Files\Last%20Document=C:/temp/pr.tex
Files\Parse%20BibTeX=true
Bibliography\BibFileEncoding=UTF-8
Files\Bib%20Paths=
Files\Image%20Paths=
Session\StoreRelativePaths=true
Tools\Insert%20Unicode%20From%20SymbolGrid=false
Dialogs\Last%20Hard%20Wrap%20Column=80
Dialogs\Last%20Hard%20Wrap%20Smart%20Scope%20Selection=false
Dialogs\Last%20Hard%20Wrap%20Join%20Lines=false
Tools\SingleViewerInstance=false
Tools\Show%20Messages%20When%20Compiling=true
Tools\Show%20Stdout=1
Tools\Automatic%20Rerun%20Times=5
Tools\ReplaceEnvironmentVariables=true
Tools\SupportShellStyleLiteralQuotes=true
Tools\Log%20Paths=
Tools\PDF%20Paths=
Tools\Auto%20Checkin%20after%20Save%20level=0
Tools\SVN%20Undo=false
Tools\SVN%20KeywordSubstitution=false
Tools\SVN%20Search%20Path%20Depth=2
GUI\Style=false
GUI\Texmaker%20Palette=false
GUI\Use%20System%20Theme=true
Interface\Config%20Show%20Advanced%20Options=true
Interface\Config%20Riddled=true
Interface\New%20Left%20Panel%20Layout=true
Interface\MRU%20Document%20Chooser=false
Interface\Language=en
LogView\WarnIfFileSizeLargerMB=2
Tools\User%20Class=@Invalid()
Tools\User%20Paper=@Invalid()
Tools\User%20Encoding=@Invalid()
Tools\User%20Options=@Invalid()
Tools\Quick%20Mode=-2
Tools\Max%20Expanding%20Nesting%20Deep=10
Tools\Dvi2Png%20Mode=0
Files\Save%20Files%20Before%20Compiling=2
Preview\Remove%20Beamer%20Class=true
Preview\Precompile%20Preamble=true
Tools\Automatic%20Rerun%20Commands=latex|pdflatex|xelatex|lualatex|compile
User\ToolNames=@Invalid()
User\Tools=@Invalid()
Tools\Display%20Names=:knitr
Tools\User%20Order=knitr
Tools\Preview%20Compile%20Time%20Out=15000
Tools\Had%20Successful%20Process%20Start=true
Files\Default%20File%20Filter=TeX files (*.tex *.bib *.sty *.cls *.mp *.dtx *.cfg *.ins *.ltx *.tikz *.pdf_tex)
PDFSplitter=0.56104824300178679
Tools\Kind\LaTeX=latex, pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex, latexmk, compile
Tools\Kind\Rerunnable=latex, pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex
Tools\Kind\Pdf=pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex, latexmk, dvipdf, ps2pdf
Tools\Kind\Stdout=bibtex, biber, bibtex8, bibliography
Tools\Kind\Viewer=view-pdf, view-ps, view-dvi, view-pdf-internal, view-pdf-external, view
Crash%20Handler%20Type=1
qttwp\userwidth=700
qttwp\compil=1
qttwp\tocdepth=2
qttwp\startindex=1
qttwp\navigation=1
qttwp\noindex=false
qttwp\title=
qttwp\address=
qttwp\browser=\"C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/IEXPLORE.EXE\"
qttwp\contentname=\\contentsname
qttwp\align=center
qttwp\lastdir=C:/Users/banana
qttwp\dviopt=" -Ppk -V"
Tools\After%20BibTeX%20Change=tmx://latex && tmx://bibtex && tmx://latex
User\New%20Key%20Replacements%20Created=true
customCommands=@Invalid()
Symbols\Quantity=@Variant(\0\0\0\b\0\0\0\0)
Symbols\Favorite%20IDs=@Invalid()
Symbols\hiddenlists=
Tools\Commands\knitr=R -e \"knitr::knit2pdf('%.Rnw')\" | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///view-pdf-internal
```

PD:  Finally I've decided to delete the configuration file.  It seems to work. Now the precompile field is empty.

Comment: If you tell it to update the bibliography before compiling and then tell it that recompiling the bibliography requires first compiling, might the programme not have a legitimate gripe? Note: I don't use this editor. This is simply *a priori*.

Comment: But I'm not using any bibliography nor telling it to do it.

Comment: You are telling it to do that before compilation. Your preferences say so!

Comment: You seem to have built in a loop in your texstudio scripts. That both "Precompile" and "Internat Precompile" are identical looks suspicious.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you think is a problem with my TexStudio configuration, with my Texlive configuration or something else?

Comment: It is a texstudio error, so imho you are doing something wrong in its configuration. Be aware that the `txs:///...` are like macros. They can call other macros and if they call themselves again you get an endless loop.

Comment: I've added the content of texstudio.ini summarized.  It seems the definition of Tools\Commands\pre-compile is different from the other, it contains quotes in a different place, but I've never changed that. Anyway, changing that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: The problem happens even when I just press the option pdfLatex, that runs "C:/texlive/2016/bin/win32/pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Comment: Maybe try with the factory settings? I think they are https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVUNZ.png But if you are not using any bibliography  or similar, I would simply use `txs:///pdflatex | txs://view` for "Build and View".

Comment: `Tools\Commands\pre-compile` calls itself with `txs:///pre-compile`

Comment: @samcarter those are my settings. I'm not using biliography but I will.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think you found the problem, now I have to find the solution.

Comment: I've finally deleted the settings file. Now the precompile field is empty. And it seems to work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user solved the problem by deleting the config. (See end of question.)

Answer (score 3):

As @Ulrike Fischer stated in the comments, `Tools\Commands\pre-compile` calls itself. This causes an infinite loop. Deleting or modifying the entry for `precompile` will solve the issue.